# Multiple automated comments from same user below answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review-queues, comments, automatic-comments

I've already seen the another post mentioning the additional comments simply adds noice and love the suggestion to convert them into upvotes for the first one.

But then I came across this while going through the review queue:

> [image: Triple comment]

How come the same comment get added twice from the same user?

*Update:* Not sure if this is specific to one user, found the same again:

> [image: Double comment]

**Update:**

According to [Eugene's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3745022/eugene-podskal) [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269049/2333214), double clicking the delete button (*or such review buttons*) triggers this behavior.

- If so, does it count as another delete votes as well? If is does isn't it a bug?
- If the second click doesn't count as another vote, then obviously already there is some validation which is missing for the autocomments.

Can't we have the same for auto comments as well?

Comment: Maybe they copied it in there twice. You can flag one of them as too chatty and it will likely get removed.

Comment: Why would someone do that..?! i believe this is a bug...

Comment: I've done it myself when I've had a poor connection, I've managed to accidentally double post things. It happens.

Comment: @Joe this comment usually gets added automatically by the system according to one's review choice. Are you saying that somebody actually copies these exact same comments including the link, and manually finds appropriate low quality posts and comments below it..?

Comment: No, it is no different than commenting manually, some user interaction is triggering this. On a poor connection, that user interaction may (appear) to have happened twice. Of course, I'm speculating.

Comment: I actually meant to reply to the first comment. Still isn't it a bug? We shouldn't be able to post same thing over and over again repeatedly IMHO.

Comment: I know I added the first comment by hand, because I hoped the poster would elaborate on how to use expect4j, and the answer wasn't in my review queue, nor could I flag it as "Not an answer" because it clearly is an answer. Maybe that confused the system?

Comment: Perhaps the reviewer used the "back" button to check a previous review and it got posted again? I used the back and forth buttons a lot when reviewing

Comment: @staticx <OCD> I think the proper reason is "obsolete" not "too chatty". The user most likely isn't chatting with himself </OCD> ;)

Answer (score 28):

There is no mystery - just my mouse at home has recently turned a bit buggy (sometimes making double clicks instead of single clicks) and the "Delete" button got triggered twice before the pop-up window closed.

There were no evil intentions from me or bugs on SO server (client is not so innocent however). Well, popup window can block itself while closing, but as overall it is not a grave defect, and it is quite difficult to trigger in normal conditions.

But I have seen similar double posts from other users, and whether such issues have the same reasons in their cases or not I have no idea whatsoever.

**P.S.:** Let's hope that e-commerce sites do not similarly allow you to pay twice for ordered goods.

**P.S.1:** I have just replaced my mouse to spare one, so my issue probably won't repeat itself :)

Comment: P.P.S. I'm not even angry.

Comment: "*There were no evil intentions from me*" Ha! Prove it!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You have to trust me, or I'll be forced to come to you and replace your mouse with my old buggy one. )

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know that the post is't about a user having evil intentions... it is just a *possible* bug report, couldn't remove the name since the *same user* thing is important here...

Comment: @TJ No offence taken. And yes, it is the client side bug, but as I have already said "it is quite difficult to trigger in normal conditions.", so whether it should be fixed or left alone as unimportant is a moot topic.

Comment: Despite my best efforts, I cannot reproduce this manually. So for now it's [tag:status-norepro]